# javascript/jquery : Window.open opens child window but after few seconds child window get automatically closed for some urls(for IE and chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, window.open

I have a link on page which opens a new child window(using window.open), but in IE and google chrome browsers new child window opens and close immediately but it is working for some urls.

Here is the js fiddle for the same :

```
[Demo]http://jsfiddle.net/pJgyu/36395/
```

As you can see in the js fiddle, when clicking on Login link in Chrome browser child window opens and close immediately but it working for url commented in the code as "https://europay.smart2pay.com/SignIn.aspx".

This works good in firefox but I am getting this issue only in IE and chrome. Can anyone has any idea on what is happening here.

Thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because this code is executed on init on https://wpc.gcsip.com/wpc/wpc page

```
// check that this page is not in a subwindow (e.g. after a session time out)
if ( window.opener ) {
    window.opener.location = "wpc";
    window.opener.focus();
    window.close();
}
```

Comment: ohhh..thanks for pointing this out..now will have to look for some other approach to open this website in a popup window.

Comment: @DeanM Maybe iframe will work. You can put it in jQuery UI dialog.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion will definitely try this..But I am not understanding one thing how it is working in FF browser, why in FF browser child window is not getting closed?

Comment: @jcubic iframe option is good, but it blocks the complete UI, in my case I have to access previous screen while new window is opened